# How to get rid of "File Modified Externally" modal after saving in Aginity for Netezza

Tags: netezza

I am new to Aginity for Netezza and every time I save a file, it always pops up a box that says the file was modified outside the SQL Editor and would I like to reload it? It's mostly an annoyance. Clicking Yes or No doesn't seem to even make a difference although once I thought my changes weren't saved. Anyone know how to stop this popup?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same bug in Aginity Workbench for PureData System for Analytics version 4.9.1.2686 (build 05/11/17) on Windows 7, and I confirmed it is caused by external modification of the corporate McAfee anti-virus scanner.

I can see the file-modified date is milliseconds more recent than the created date, and Aginity support refused to consider a change to ignore changes quicker than one second. (For comparison, Notepad++ has the feature, but it does not have this problem.)

Workarounds include:

1. Save the file to a network drive instead of local drive such as C:
2. Disable McAfee
3. Set up a whitelist in McAfee
4. Live with the annoyance
5. Disable the feature in Aginity. Click *Tools - Options - Query Analyzer - Check if the opened files are modified externally*.

Comment: Interesting... unfortunately I am not currently working in Aginity or Netezza anymore to verify or try these out, but that could have been my problem. I bet that company had McAfee and #5 seems like an easy fix, didn't notice that option

Comment: #5 (Disabling the feature) is what Aginity support suggested to me, but I sometimes edit the same file in Aginity and Notepad++. The latter is useful to reformat SQL using the Poor Man's SQL reformatter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

That popup is indicating that the file has changed since you had it open.  Same type of warning that you would get in `Notepad++` there isn't a way to disable the notice.  It seems that you are opening files that others are editing at the same time.

Comment: I am editing files on my own hard drive that no one else is using- I'm working independently on these files. I'm wondering if it's a bug.

Comment: In another program like `notepad` or `winsql`?

Comment: @niederee Yeah I agree, i think this is standard behavior if you are working with a file in multiple ides.

Comment: I might possibly know why this is happening. Unbeknownst to me, I had a whole different query "window" with all the same tabs and files open- I saw this by going to Window in the menu. So once I closed this other window and all its tabs, and I try saving a file, I am not getting the error. I think this new window got loaded at some point today when I did a reconnect after my session/connection timed out. I don't see a way to reconnect without opening a new window.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it after all. Message still occurring

Comment: Maybe it is a bug.  I was unable to replicate it in `Version 4.0.998.20231 (build 2/14/2013)`